# What is the Rails way to handle adding a required attribute on an existing model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-migrations

For example, I recently added 'address' fields to my user model. They are being validated by presence. So now, when I went to update a different attribute, email for example, I can't save the user because it has invalid fields (the address is still blank).

Do you just have to migrate the data with blank strings or something?

What is the Rails way to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

One way to handle this is to populate the new field in the migration which creates it. That way, you're ensuring that everything in the database is valid according to the model. The [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#using-models-in-your-migrations) has some pointers on doing this - there are a couple of gotchas.

Another way is by specifying that the validation only runs on creation, not on updates, with the `:on` option. That might look like:

```
validates :address, :presence => true, :on => :create
```

That way, any new user has to have the address set, but you're still able to edit other attributes on existing users.

Comment: Your link to that section of the guide was exactly what I needed to solve a different problem that I was having with a migration, thank you. However, I think adding bogus data to the database doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: I have another idea; updating the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you do the migration every time you add new fields and put validations on them.
It would keep the data integrity and consistency.

If you really want to do a trick, adding conditions on validation, putting "validate: false" conditionally when you do save, adding blank value for address fields when you modify an existing records all are tricks you can use.

I also suggest that when you add address, create a address model and share it among other models which need it, instead of only adding fields into the models.  That would make your validation more flexible.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, we ended up using your recommendation of passing the save method :validate => false in our model, but it still seems like it opens up errors in the future having to remember to add this for any new attribute on my model. I unfortunately can't vote up your answer though due to my low reputation.